# PHP mysql data not retrieving from last id

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm developing one API in php to display data on android app from my database using JSON.

In my app I want to display 20 records first, after display again 20 records once user scroll to top.
I'm requesting the last id of the record from app to show next 20 records from last id.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$last_movie = 0;
$genre = $_REQUEST['genre'];
$last_movie = $_REQUEST['lastid'];

require_once("connect.php");
$myArray = array();

if($last_movie == 0)
{
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM my_movies WHERE genre = '$genre' ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 20");
}
else
{
     $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM my_movies WHERE genre = '$genre' ORDER BY year LIMIT ".$last_movie.",20");

}

if ($result) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}

$result->close();
$conn->close();



?>
```

I'm getting values in some genres, but sometimes it show empty JSON.
I tried with this url
http://freemodedapk.com/bobmovies/by_genre.php?genre=Action

its working , whenever I try from last id
http://freemodedapk.com/bobmovies/by_genre.php?genre=Action&lastid=4714

It returns empty JSON. I have values in database.

---

But some genres working fine
http://freemodedapk.com/bobmovies/by_genre.php?genre=Drama
http://freemodedapk.com/bobmovies/by_genre.php?genre=Drama&lastid=865

I have total 4858 records in the database with all genres.

Anybody can help me to fix empty JSON problems in some of genres ?

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is in the wrong LIMIT usage: when you utilize 2 parameters for LIMIT keyword, the first one is for OFFSET value (not for IDs), the second one is to limit your result.

In short words: you should use LIMIT 0,20 to get the first 20 results, LIMIT 20,20 to show next 20 results and so on.

Also, your code is insecure - you have SQL injection. Try to not post direct urls on your sites with the source code which includes injection because some bad guys may drop your database or do some other harmful things.

Sample code is listed below (minor changes may be required):

```
<?php

require_once('connect.php');

$response = [];

$items_per_page = 20;

$page = (int) (($_REQUEST['page'] - 1) * $items_per_page);

$genre = $conn->escape_string($genre); # replace escape_string with proper method if necessary

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM my_movies WHERE genre = '$genre' ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT $page,$items_per_page");

if ($result)
{
    $response = $conn->fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); # replace fetch_all with proper method if necessary
}

echo json_encode($response);

$result->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: But id is not like 10,20.. id is changing on genres

Comment: The fact is you should not care about your last id from the previous page. You should use only OFFSET and LIMIT to display "pages". Forget about ids.

Comment: I have different categories, I want to display each categories separately. so id will be not straight sequence.

Comment: I need to display every category separately. First 20 records after again 20 from the last record.

Comment: The sample code is in my answer. You should pass "page = 1" to see the first set of data, "page = 2" to see the second one and so on.

Comment: I'm getting blank screen. I think you didn't understood my problem ?

Comment: I think you should read official documentation first. Your problem is that you think that solution is X when in fact solution is Y. First of all, google "MySQL LIMIT" and try to understand the usage. At least it's better than tell me "NO, YOU DON'T UNDERSTAND".

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to get last ID to ASC then use to

```
SELECT * FROM my_movies WHERE genre = '$genre' id<".$last_movie." ORDER BY year LIMIT 0,20
```

> or if you want to get for pagination then your OFFSET value wrong,

you should be use LIMIT 0,20 to get the first 20 results, LIMIT 20,20 to next 20 , LIMIT 40,20

### please check your SQL injection

look like Code

```
require_once('connect.php');
$result = [];
$limit = 20;
$pageNumber = (int) (($_REQUEST['pageNumber'] - 1) * $limit);
$genre = $conn->escape_string($genre);

$getDta = $conn->query("SELECT id,title,stream,trailer,directors,actors,quality,year,genre,length,translation,rating,description,poster FROM my_movies WHERE genre = '".$genre."' ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT $pageNumber,$limit");

if ($result)
    $result =$conn->fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);

$result->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Check here 
http://freemodedapk.com/bobmovies/by_genre.php?genre=Drama&lastid=1125

Comment: this is working, but some genres not working.... I need to load more items from last record to app

Comment: http://freemodedapk.com/bobmovies/by_genre.php?genre=Action&pageNumber=2

Comment: Getting empty JSON

Comment: Instead of passing the id of movie, we have divide it by pages